# MariaDB ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN infinite

Tags: mariadb, alter-table

I use below command to drop a column activetime from my table. While this command never end. I waited for 5 mins while there is only 100 records in MY_TABLENAME

ALTER TABLE MY_TABLENAME DROP COLUMN `activetime`;

The column activetime is defined as below:

| activetime         | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |

Comment: Open another connection and run `SHOW PROCESSLIST`. If your `ALTER TABLE` has something like `Waiting for ... lock`, it means the table is locked by some other connection, then use the same processlist output to see what can be locking it.

Comment: SHOW PROCESSLIST is very helpful, there is another application connecting to this database, I skilled that application and could drop the column successfully now. Thanks!